# Wordpress and laravel

Tags: wordpress, laravel

I want to use laravel 5 and wordpress cms together as frontend and backend respectly and trying  to load wordpress posts to laravel using WP_Query.I would like to know that how to display images in laravel's view page ?

Answer (score 2):

Check out these:

http://grossi.io/2014/working-with-laravel-4-and-wordpress-together/

[Laravel 5 and Wordpress 4.1.1 in the same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29316546/laravel-5-and-wordpress-4-1-1-in-the-same-server)